# Python code and display with php

Tags: php, python

I have a Python and a PHP program, for a display application in a web browser. This is the PHP code:

```
<div id="container">
    <h1>Summarizer</h1>

    <form action="." method="post">
        <p>
            <label for="text">Text:</label>
        </p>
        <p>
            <textarea id="text" name="text">{{ text }}</textarea>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="number">Number of sentences:
                <input type="number" min="1" value="{{ number }}" name="number" id="number"/>
            </label>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="language">Language:
                <select name="language" id="language">
                    % for a_language in available_languages:
                        <option value="{{ a_language }}"{{ " selected" if language == a_language else "" }}>{{ a_language.capitalize() }}</option>
                    % end
                </select>
            </label>
        </p>
        <p>
            <button type="submit" id="submit">Summarize</button>
        </p>
    </form>

    % if result:
    <h2>Result</h2>
    <p>
        {{ result }}
    </p>
    % end
</div>
```

And this is the Python code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from bottle import Bottle, request, view
from summarize import summarize

DEMO_TEXT = (
    "Alice and Bob are friends. Alice is fun and cuddly. Bob is cute and"
    " quirky. Together they go on wonderful adventures in the land of"
    " tomorrow. Alice's cuddliness and Bob's cuteness allow them to reach"
    " their goals. But before they get to them, they have to go past their"
    " mortal enemy — Mr. Boredom. He is ugly and mean. They will surely"
    " defeat him. He is no match for their abilities."
)

LANGUAGES = (
    'danish',
    'dutch',
    'english',
    'finnish',
    'french',
    'german',
    'italian',
    'norwegian',
    'portuguese',
    'spanish',
    'swedish',
)

app = Bottle()

@app.route('/', method='GET')
@app.route('/', method='POST')
@view('index')
def index():
    text = request.forms.getunicode('text')
    number = int_or_none(request.forms.get('number'))
    language = request.forms.get('language') or 'english'
    result = summarize(text, number, language) if number and text else None
    return {
        'text': text or DEMO_TEXT,
        'result': result,
        'number': number or 5,
        'language': language,
        'available_languages': LANGUAGES
    }


def int_or_none(value):
    try:
        return int(value)
    except TypeError:
        return None


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

I have run into a problem. The value in the Python code, can't display in the PHP code. How would I go about fixing this? I am running this code in Windows, and not on Linux. Thanks in advance.

Comment: why use 2 languages whn 1 will do?

Comment: It looks like you are confusing PHP with Django's template language. While there are similarities - they both mix HTML with other "stuff" - they are quite different. I suggest removing the PHP tag and all references to PHP and take a hard look at how the template language works.

Comment: because i am wont trying this code from windows os. Before this code run in linux os.

Comment: its jinja2 not PHP. http://jinja.pocoo.org/ .any http response? errors?

Comment: ok. I Have a jinja2. But code is stay not work.